# Regex for Backward Look up

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have a string that I want to parse with Python.
I am new to regex, so really appreciate help.

```
ABC_XYZ::A_BCD_XYZ_C9_KDFJ_7011_1_11_14
```

Output `C9` : Always starts with letter and a digit

Output `7011`: Always 4 or more digits

Output `1, 11, 14`: Always at the end of the string. One or two digits. May have more than 3.

Update.

I was using `[^_]+` and it parses everything '_'. I wanted just those matches.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. sorry for not including the detail. I have update the question. I was using '_' as the delimiter but was not sure how to parse those exact matches.

Comment: @Imsa: Do the substrings always occur at the same places? You might simply want to split on `_` and pick the correct fields.

Comment: @Jan no, they don't. In addition, the last part (one or two digits) can occur many times.

Comment: @Imsa: Please provide two or three other strings to see the pattern.

Comment: `_([A-Za-z]\d)(?=_).*?_(\d{4})_([\d_]+)$` [will get you](https://regex101.com/r/XEvzA5/1) what you need, just split that last group (3) value with `_`

Comment: Does "One or two digits. May have more than 3." mean one or more digits but not two and that `1`, `11` , `14` are just examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get along with

```
import re

def get_values(string):
    rx = re.compile(r'_([A-Z]\d)_.*?_(\d{4,}(?=_)).*?((?:_\d{1,2})+)')
    m = rx.search(string)
    if m:
        return (m.group(1), m.group(2), [item for item in m.group(3).split("_") if item])

print(get_values("ABC_XYZ::A_BCD_XYZ_C9_KDFJ_7011_1_11_14"))
# ('C9', '7011', ['1', '11', '14'])
```

See a [**demo for the expression**](https://regex101.com/r/HAUkvp/1) on regex101.com.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this regex

```
((?<=_)\d{4})|((?<=_)\w?\d{1})
```

https://regex101.com/r/0fhJFY/1

Comment: then you can use this regex ((?<=_)\d{4})|([a-zA-Z ]?\d{1,4})  https://regex101.com/r/u96yG5/1

Comment: @CarySwoveland did you check?

Comment: Whoops. You are correct, on both counts. It does match and I didn't check. Not only that, I didn't examine your regex carefully. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand what you need exactly but the regex:

```
[^_]+_[^_]+::[^_]_[^_]+_[^_]+_([A-Z]\d)_[^_]+_(\d{4,})_(\d)_(\d+)_(\d+)
```

give the output you want for the string you provided.

To test and learn regex I advise you to visit site like [this](https://regex101.com/r/NKASy1/1).

Comment: This is good. but it only parses if last part of the string has 3 numbers. could be N.